# IP Address in between 2 routers?

Tags: networking, routes, cisco

I'm new to networking and pretty bad at subnetting. Could someone explain to me what's happening between Pescara and Pauillac? What is the 10.1.1.12/30 IP? I know the 30 is because of the 255.255.255.252 Mask. But the document I am using doesn't refer to this 10.1.1.12/30 anywhere.

- Pescara is a PE Router
- Pauillac is a P Router

The document I am talking about is [here](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/multiprotocol-label-switching-mpls/mpls/13733-mpls-vpn-basic.html#c2). It is about MPLS VPN Configuration.

Edit: Some more info: Pescara is using Subinterfaces to communicate to Pauillac. Am I to use 2 serial links?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `10.1.1.12/30` is just the subnet being used for the two interconnected interfaces. If you look at each connection they have a `.13` and `.14`, this is because their IPs are `10.1.1.13` and `10.1.1.14`  respectively of the subnet `10.1.1.12/30`

Answer (score 0):

.252 in binary is 11111100, so there are 2 bits for the host field.  This bits can be 00, 01, 10, or 11.  00 is the ​network link itself, 01 and 10 are the valid host addresses, and 11 is the broadcast address for the network link.

12 in binary is 00001100.  Putting it all together:

```
00001100 = .12 network link itself
00001101 = .13 first host address
00001110 = .14 second host address
00001111 = .16 broadcast address for the network link
```